# Trying to create a Categorised Index (archive?) to use as my Home Page

Tags: categories, pages

I am making a site that will have posts on several subjects, and often in multi-part posts.

I would like a Home page that can display a Categorised Index, so that visitors can easily find the relevant Posts.

I am currently using the [archive] tag, but that creates a full list of posts with no distinction between them.

Is it possible to create a List that will automatically split my posts into Categories e.g.

Posts with Category “Windows”:

- post 1
- post 2
- post 3

Posts with Category “Linux”

- post 5
- post 7
- post 10

Posts with Category “Security”

- post 2
- post 4
- post 6

etc

I would just like the Post Titles, as links, rather than whole posts, or "Preview” posts.

I am using TwentySixteen Theme, but am prepared to change, if a more appropriate one would work better.

The page I need help with: https://thepcwizarduk.com/wp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will first iterate and display all the categories with ID 2, 3 and 4. And the second loop will display all the posts within each of the category.

```
<?php
$_categories = get_categories( array(
            'orderby' => 'order',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'include' => array(2,3,4) // put the category IDs here
        ) );

// Loop to display each of the Category
foreach( $_categories as $_category ) :

    $_posts = get_posts( array(
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'category__in' => array( $_category->term_id ),
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ) );

    if( $_posts ) :

        echo '<section id="category-'. intval($_category->term_id) .'" class="category-block">';

            echo '<h1 class="category-title">'. esc_html($_category->name) .'<h1>';

            echo '<div class="category-articles">';

                // Loop to display posts of certain a category
                foreach( $_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
                    echo '<article id="post-'. get_the_ID() .'" class="'. join( ' ', get_post_class( '', get_the_ID() ) ) .'">';
                        echo '<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">'. get_the_title() .'</a>';
                    echo '</article>';
                endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();

            echo '</div>';

            // A link to the Category archive
            echo '<a href="'. get_category_link( $_category->term_id ) .'" title="'. sprintf( esc_attr__( "View all posts in %s" ), $_category->name ) .'"></a>';

        echo '</section>';

    endif;

endforeach;
```

## Templating

### Page Template or Shortcode

If you want to stick with the WordPress' default standard, then make a [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) or a [Shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) with the code above and set a WordPress page as Front Page from **Settings » Reading** in admin end, and use the Page Template or Shortcode to let the code run on your front page.

### Static Front Page

If you want to set a [static front page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#front-page-display), create a `front-page.php` in your Child theme, and add the code above in that page to let it work on your front page.

> **Remember**
>   If you are changing in your theme, DON'T work on TwentySixteen, you will loose your work on the next release. Make a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and put your changes there.

## Resources

1. [`get_categories` — WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)
2. [`get_posts` — WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/)

Comment: Minor errors in code:
echo '<article id="post-'. get_the_ID() .'" class="'. join( ' ', get_post_class( '', get_the_ID() ) .'">'; //Missing )    should be:   get_the_ID() )) . ">';     I presume
No closing   ?>

I built front-page.php with this (corrected) code, and it worked, but with NO formatting. Just a plain page, no headers, sidebar etc.
I have tried a shortcode, building a new Page with just [listcat] and it displays a blank page. :(

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the missing bracket. When working with HTML inside shortcode, Object Buffering would be your friend: use `ob_start();` before whole HTML block, and `return ob_get_clean();` at the end. [Example here](https://github.com/nanodesigns/adzonia/blob/0fbb5a95d81d9fd63b91cdc060656a32f443cb0c/includes/shortcodes/adzonia-shortcode.php#L30-L32).

Comment: I now have the page basically working, using a Page Template. Good enough for now. I shall investigate ob_start();.